# Override attribute in FosUserBundle, make email and emailCanonical nullable true

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm using Symfony2.6 and I'd like to make email and emailCanonical nullable=true  in FosUserBundle :

```
/**
* @ORM\Entity
* @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
* @ORM\AttributeOverrides({
*              @ORM\AttributeOverride(name="email", column=@ORM\Column(nullable=true)),
*              @ORM\AttributeOverride(name="emailCanonical", column=@ORM\Column(nullable=true, unique=false))
*
* })
*/
```

Updating database works fine , but when I execute this command

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities UserBundle
```

I get this error

```
[Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException]
Invalid field override named 'email' for class 'UserBundle\Entity\User'.
```

Comment: It's a known bug, https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/issues/982 , Hope a fix will be provided soon. Not sure about it's related to FOSUser and not Doctrine at all.

Comment: change it on the super class